# NodeJS - recursively retrieve environment variable value using WINREG module

Tags: node.js, winreg

I am searching for a NodeJS implementation of:

```
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment" /s /v CLIENTNAME
```

Which **recursively** searches the *\Volatile Environment*  registry for a CLIENTNAME variable.

**Right now the solution I have is:**

```
var Registry = require( 'winreg' ),
    regKey = new Registry( {
        hive: Registry.HKCU,
        key: "\\Volatile Environment\\3\\" // for my use-case, the \\3\\ varies and I need something Dynamic
    } );

regKey.get( Registry.DEFAULT_VALUE, function( err, item ) {

    if ( err ) {
        console.log( "Error get: " );
        console.log( err );
    }
    else {
        console.log( "Success get: " );
        console.dir( item.value );
    }

} );
```

Is there some elegant way to make the key path dynamic?

Comment: Take a look into async module. There are plenty answers about it on SO. https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution I wrote this event-emitting recursive function (I am not marking this as an accepted answer, since I was definitely expecting something in the lines of changing an argument value in the [WINREG](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winreg) library)

**Since I am just learning NodeJS, I made a component out of it for fun:**

```
var EventEmitter = require( 'events' ).EventEmitter;

function RegistryDataEvents( env_var_name ) {
    this.events = undefined;
    this.initEvents( env_var_name );
} // cunstruct RegistryDataEvents

RegistryDataEvents.prototype.initEvents = function( env_var_name ) {
    this.events = new EventEmitter();
    var _that = this;
    process.nextTick(
        function() {
            _that.retrieveClientName( 0, false, "", env_var_name );
        }
    );
}; // initEvents

module.exports.RegistryDataEvents = RegistryDataEvents;

RegistryDataEvents.prototype.rerun = function( env_var_name ) {

    this.retrieveClientName( 0, false, "", env_var_name );

}; // rerun

RegistryDataEvents.prototype.retrieveClientName = function( count, 
                                                            found, 
                                                            result, 
                                                            env_var_name ) {
    var _that = this;
    if ( count === 0 ) {
        _that.events.emit( 'start', result );
    }
    if ( found ) {
        _that.events.emit( 'success', result );
        return;
    }
    var key = "\\Volatile Environment\\"+ count +"\\";
    var Registry = require( './registry.js' ),
        regKey = new Registry( {
            hive: Registry.HKCU,
            key: key
        } );

    regKey.get( env_var_name, function( err, item ) {
        if ( err ) {
            // obviously this is a downfall of the module, any suggestions will be appreciated :)
            if ( count > 100 ) {
                _that.events.emit( 'failure', result, err, count );
                return;
            }
            _that.retrieveClientName( ++count, false, "", env_var_name );
        }
        else {
            found = true;
            _that.retrieveClientName( ++count, true, item.value, env_var_name );
            return;
        }
    } );
    return;
}; // retrieveClientName
```

**Usage**

```
var RegistryDataEvents = require( './reg_data_evts.js' ).RegistryDataEvents;

// Register the event + listeners
var reg_data_evts = new RegistryDataEvents( "CLIENTNAME" );

// handle listener logic
reg_data_evts.events.on( 'start', function( result ) {
    console.log( "Started " + result );
} );

reg_data_evts.events.on( 'success', function( result ) {
    console.log( "Success: " + result );
} );

reg_data_evts.events.on( 'failure', function( result, err, count ) {
    console.log( "Failure: " + result + " - " + err + " after " + count + " attempts" );
} );

// just to show u can rerun the retrieveClientName method
reg_data_evts.rerun( "CLIENTNAME" );
// just to show u can rerun the retrieveClientName method
reg_data_evts.rerun( "CLIENTNAME" );
```